# Pandas - Unique ID based on values in prior row

Tags: python, pandas

I'm creating a ID for group of rows, where the ID is based on the values in the previous row.  I've currently accomplished this using a for loop, but since there are so many rows, this is very slow.  is there an easier way to do this?

Specifically, I create a new unique ID when the category and value does not equal the category and value of the prior row.

```
df = date     category value
     1/1/2018 A        0
     1/2/2018 A        0
     1/3/2018 A        1
     1/4/2018 A        0
     1/1/2018 AB       1
     1/2/2018 AB       1
     1/3/2018 AB       1
     1/4/2018 ABC      0

df_out = date     category value unique_id
         1/1/2018 A        0     1
         1/2/2018 A        0     1
         1/3/2018 A        1     2
         1/4/2018 A        0     3
         1/1/2018 AB       1     4
         1/2/2018 AB       1     4
         1/3/2018 AB       1     4
         1/4/2018 ABC      0     5
```

Answer (score 3):

The following method is not necessarily faster than your loop but at least it does not have any explicit looping. Start by taking the difference between the next and previous values. The difference is not equal to zero when the value changes:

```
val_diff = df['value'].diff().fillna(0) != 0 # Boolean!
```

The same trick won't work for the category, because characters cannot be subtracted. Get a list of all unique categories, enumerate them, and use the enumerated values instead of the category names:

```
unique = df['category'].unique()
unique_mapping = {y:x for x,y in enumerate(unique)}

cat_diff = df['category'].replace(unique_mapping)\
                         .diff().fillna(0) != 0
```

The id increases when either the value of the category changes:

```
df['id'] = (val_diff | cat_diff).cumsum() + 1
df
#       date category  value  id
#0  1/1/2018        A      0   1
#1  1/2/2018        A      0   1
#2  1/3/2018        A      1   2
#3  1/4/2018        A      0   3
#4  1/1/2018        B      1   4
#5  1/2/2018        B      1   4
#6  1/3/2018        B      1   4
#7  1/4/2018        B      0   5
```

Comment: Unfortunately category are not strictly single-character. Should have been more clear in question. Updated question to reflect.

Comment: You could use the original `shift` pattern instead of the diff trick, e.g. `keys = df[["category", "value"]]; (keys != keys.shift()).any(axis=1).cumsum()`.

Comment: @DSM Sure. Feel free to post it as an answer.